# Can I backup my whatsapp data from an iOS 8 device and use it on an iOS 7 Device?

Tags: ios, icloud, backup, whatsapp.app

I used to have an iPhone 4s which is broken now, and I got an iPhone 4 from a friend who doesn't need it anymore. I made a backup off my whatsapp chats via iCloud Drive (which doesn't exist on iOS 7), so I can't use them on the iPhone 4. By reading the [Whatsapp FAQ](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/iphone/20888066#backup) I get the impression that this might be completely impossible. Is there any way I can have my chats on the iOS 7 device? It doesn't have to be via iCloud, and I don't mind investing some time to try a few things. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) I'm thinking about your dilemma and was wondering if you could clarify what you mean by your iPhone 4s being broken now? Also, do you have access to a Mac or PC and, if so, what? Also, are you using the same SIM card in the iPhone 4 that you had in the 4s? If not, are you still using the same mobile number? With regard to WhatsApp itself, do you have the same version installed on the iPhone 4 that you did on the iPhone 4s?

Comment: @Monomeeth: The Power button is not working anymore, and the screen is completely shattered - it's still somewhat useable, but not for long I guess. Yes I do have access to both (Mac only a VM). Yes I'm using the same SIM and the same mobile number. I have the newest whatsapp version available on the respective iOS version, but I'll have to check whether it's the same on both phones.

Comment: Jailbreaking an option? I think just replacing the screen and button for a few dollars will help you much quicker. Those repairs are pretty cheap these days.

Answer (score 1):

Conventionally there is no way to do this between the devices but you can access WhatsApp chat logs via many of the various "iCloud Recovery Tools" out there. Syncios is the one that I use but it's around $50 (trial might do it for free) for a subscription but it does allow you to export those chat logs (I think to an XML off the top of my head). They're a dime a dozen those programs so you'll find one that suits you if it's the route you wish to take. They will require that Two Factor Authentication is disabled.

Sure you won't have them available on the device but you will in the short term have a copy of them for reference.